# How to open a rscript in Rstudio instead of in R

Tags: r, rstudio

Previously, when I clicked an r script, it opened in R studio automatically. However, today, when I clicked one, it opened in R instead of R studio. I changed nothing in the system. How can I make it go back to the old way?

Comment: operating system?

Comment: Finally I fixed it. By the way, I use IOS system. Just right click and change the "open with" in "get info". Sorry I asked a silly question. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:
Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs -> Set Associations

Find and double click on the .r extension, which will allow you to choose your desired default program (RStudio).

You can do this with other R-related file types as well.